# How to display only 5 rows in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

in the first example, I want to display all names starting with the letter given by the user. The problem is that when I enter a letter, it displays an error that, for example, the letter A should be declared. However, there is no problem when I enter the number. In the second example, however, I want to display only 5 lines using% ROWCOUNT.

```
DECLARE
    v_letter varchar2(1):=&given_letter;
    f_name Hr.Employees.first_name%TYPE;
    l_name Hr.Employees.last_name%TYPE;
    CURSOR cursor1 IS
    SELECT first_name, last_name FROM Hr.Employees where last_name like '%v_letter';
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor1;
    loop
        FETCH kursor1 INTO f_name, l_name;
        exit when cursor1%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(First name || ' ' || last name);
    end loop;
  CLOSE cursor1;
END;


DECLARE
    f_name Hr.Employees.first_name%TYPE;
    l_name Hr.Employees.last_name%TYPE;
    CURSOR cursor1 IS
    SELECT first_name, last_name FROM Hr.Employees order by salary DESC;
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor1;
    loop
        FETCH cursor1 INTO f_name, l_name;
        exit when cursor1%ROWCOUNT;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(First name || ' ' || last name);
    end loop;
  CLOSE cursor1;
END;
```

Comment: you declare and open a cursor named CURSOR1, but then you FETCH from KURSOR1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use `%rowcount`:

```
declare
    v_letter varchar2(1) := '&given_letter';
    f_name hr.employees.first_name%type;
    l_name hr.employees.last_name%type;

    cursor cursor1 is
        select first_name, last_name
        from   hr.employees
        where  last_name like v_letter||'%';
begin
    open cursor1;
    loop
        fetch cursor1 into f_name, l_name;
        exit when cursor1%notfound or cursor1%rowcount > 5;
        dbms_output.put_line(f_name || ' ' || l_name);
    end loop;

    close cursor1;
end;
/
```

Or you could simplify it to:

```
declare
    v_letter varchar2(1) := '&given_letter';
    f_name hr.employees.first_name%type;
    l_name hr.employees.last_name%type;

    cursor cursor1 is
        select first_name, last_name
        from   hr.employees
        where  last_name like v_letter||'%';
begin
    for r in cursor1 loop
        exit when cursor1%rowcount > 5;
        dbms_output.put_line(r.first_name || ' ' || r.last_name);
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your tables so I created my own, based on Scott's `EMP` table. Disregard the fact that *jobs* represent *last names*.

Compare the following code to your attempts, fix what you think you should fix.

First example:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_letter  VARCHAR2 (1) := '&given_letter';
  3
  4     CURSOR cursor1 IS
  5        SELECT first_name, last_name
  6          FROM employees
  7         WHERE last_name LIKE v_letter || '%';
  8
  9     c1r       cursor1%ROWTYPE;
 10  BEGIN
 11     OPEN cursor1;
 12
 13     LOOP
 14        FETCH cursor1 INTO c1r;
 15
 16        EXIT WHEN cursor1%NOTFOUND;
 17        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (c1r.first_name || ' ' || c1r.last_name);
 18     END LOOP;
 19
 20     CLOSE cursor1;
 21  END;
 22  /
Enter value for given_letter: C
SMITH CLERK
ADAMS CLERK
JAMES CLERK
MILLER CLERK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Second example:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     CURSOR cursor1 IS
  3          SELECT first_name, last_name, salary
  4            FROM employees
  5        ORDER BY salary DESC;
  6
  7     c1r    cursor1%ROWTYPE;
  8     l_cnt  NUMBER := 0;
  9  BEGIN
 10     OPEN cursor1;
 11
 12     LOOP
 13        FETCH cursor1 INTO c1r;
 14
 15        EXIT WHEN    cursor1%NOTFOUND
 16                  OR l_cnt > 5;
 17        l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
 18        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (c1r.first_name || ' ' || c1r.last_name ||' '|| c1r.salary);
 19     END LOOP;
 20
 21     CLOSE cursor1;
 22  END;
 23  /
KING PRESIDENT 5000
FORD ANALYST 3000
SCOTT ANALYST 3000
JONES MANAGER 2975
BLAKE MANAGER 2850
CLARK MANAGER 2450

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: But in example 2 I should use %ROWCOUNT, I don't see where you to use it.

Comment: I don't, and you shouldn't because its value will always be `1`.